# Add multiples user controls in the delegate control "AdditionalPageHead"

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, user-controls

I have an issue here. 
I'm trying to add jquery to all my pages in sharepoint, and with jquery comes the script files in which i'm using the functions i need.

So i began to create a user control as said here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2011/04/06/adding-jquery-to-every-page-in-sharepoint-with-delegate-controls.aspx

but instead of only having the line :

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="/_layouts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" />
```

I added a line :

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="/_layouts/scripts.js" />
```

After that I added the two files in my layout folder, and created the elements.xml which is linking the control :

```
 <Control Id="AdditionalPageHead"
        Sequence="90"
        ControlSrc="~/_CONTROLTEMPLATES/Safran.Sagem.Workflows/Scripts.ascx" />
```

My problem is that it includes only one of the file. It's always the first one. So here it would be jquery.js, and if i switch the order, it would be the script.js

I tried to create two controls and two elements, but it seems that just one is enabled.

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

My bad,

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/scripts.js"></script>
```

Instead of :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/scripts.js" />
```